# Cannot run newly created springboot project with maven

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, spring-boot

So, I've just installed IntelliJ for starting developing with SpringBoot.

I was following this [guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/creating-spring-boot-projects.html), but I cannot run my project after I created the project with default values for Maven.

How can I run my new made project?

Comment: What did you try and what error do you get?

Comment: I just did what the guide told me to do and wanted to do a initial run immediately after the creation of my project, but i can't click on the run or debug button. So I tried making a run/debug configuration with the projects directory of the active project and filled in package in the profile part. This gave me a build failure.

Comment: Then please add the exact steps (and screenshots) to your question, so that we can actually understand what you tried. I still can't figure out what you exactly did from your description.

Comment: And also link or URL of the tutorial you followed might add some value to your question.

Comment: The question allready contains the link to the guide i used.. I did nothing more or less then what the guide suggest i should do plus the steps i described in my previous comment i added.

Comment: Ok, I have found the mistake I made.. I tried to run the application as a maven project and not as a java application or Springboot application. Thank you for the help anyway. :)